# Remove node edit form field validation

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

I am working on the node edit form, and I want to remove all field validation when users click on *Save as unpublished*.

Is it possible?

I didn't write any code right now, so I don't have any code to show.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, this module does the same based on user roles [Bypass Form Validations] (https://www.drupal.org/project/bypass_form_validations). take look how they do that. take look at the module to see how they implement that and it could be a good start to write your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this approach in HOOK_form_alter. Depending on validation that you want to remove... I provide you a simple example of required fields: Suppose you have an Image field that it's required, you could make it unrequired using the following:

```
$form['field_image']['widget']['0']['#required'] =  TRUE;
```

Also if you want to remove the "Alt field" for a image you could use:

```
$form['field_image']['widget']['0']['#alt_field'] =  FALSE;
```

Comment: You are altering the field configuration and not how validation works